# Voltage spike on relay switching ON

Tags: relay, induction-motor, spike

I has readed the short article about relay & inductive load.
It has a case, what i cant understand.

Prereq: Load - motor, around 3kW. No snubber.
When relay switched ON - huge voltage spike has occured.
Im understanding the spike on disabling, but what about enabling? Is it induction spark bust during contacts bounce or what?

[image]

Comment: Please add a datasheet link for the relay and tell us what voltage the coil is. I presume it's AC because of the waveform.

Comment: I think we need some more information - is this a single-phase motor?  What type of relay are you using?  How are you measuring the current?

Comment: I cant, this is just an article without additional info.

Comment: All i know it is relay, what switch AC single phase motor, controlled by low voltage DC circuit.

Comment: Well link to the article then - in your question, not in the comments. If that is someone else's graphic then you need to give credit too.

Comment: The scope is showing around 60VAC. What signal is the scope measuring?

Comment: 230VAC. Article on different language (rus), so i have no reasons to link it.

Comment: I'd speculate that it could be to do with where the oscilloscope is grounded.  If it's supposed to be measuring the voltage across a current-sense resistor but the ground isn't correctly placed then the spike could be the result of something else, but without knowing the layout of the test circuit it's impossible to say what exactly.

Comment: I have third side info, what spike is caused by counter EMF. But without explanation. Can some one comment it?

Comment: Read the value off the scope - it's not 230VAC. For all we know, this could be an induced signal. I had a worse situation when my old washing machine was operating. I'd get massive bursts of ringing on my scope - coupled via the mains wiring. Consider that the relay has switched on near the peak. There might be some arcing causing the issue, but consider the inductance of the mains wiring and the di/dt inducing a signal into the earth wire that is running parallel with the active and neutral. Try the experiment yourself- it doesn't have to be a 3kW motor - vacuum cleaner, fan, light etc